# JavaScript ctx.fill() and ctx.stroke very slow

Tags: javascript, performance

I know I am now supposed to just ask you "why is my code so slow" and give you a big amount of code, but I have this problem for a week now, and it really frustrates me.

```
function drawFront() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    var tempPosition = scene.box.func.calcPos(scene.box.names[i], 0, 0, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(tempPosition.x, tempPosition.y);
    var tempPosition = scene.box.func.calcPos(scene.box.names[i], 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(tempPosition.x, tempPosition.y);
    var tempPosition = scene.box.func.calcPos(scene.box.names[i], 1, 1, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(tempPosition.x, tempPosition.y);
    var tempPosition = scene.box.func.calcPos(scene.box.names[i], 0, 1, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(tempPosition.x, tempPosition.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    if (scene.box[scene.box.names[i]].material.useFaces == true){ //this is true
        ctx.fillStyle = scene.box[scene.box.names[i]].material.faces[0].c;
        ctx.fill();
    }
    if (scene.box[scene.box.names[i]].material.grid == true) // this is true
        ctx.stroke();
}
```

This code is supposed to draw a shape with 4 corners, all of these corner  positions are calculated using the `scene.box.func.calcPos()` function. All of this works perfectly fine, but the drawing gets slower and slower and slower as times moves by.

My CPU temperature gradually goes up from *40°C* to *80°C* and above.
What could be the cause of this?

EDIT:
here is a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/fswxtxyz/
here is the github page to the project: https://github.com/Quoteme/Fluchtpunkt3D
Thank you very very much for your help

Comment: Since that is not native JavaScript (what is `scene`? `calcPos()`?), there is no way to help you here.

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol said,since it is a performance issue need to know `scene` class and `calcPos()` method

Comment: these are just variables. They have no real meaning. calcPos just return a x and a y value. And scene is just stores all this information. It does not have an impact on the performance though. If you would like my whole code, I can upload it. Thank you very very very much for looking into it though

Comment: I'm guessing the scene object is from three.js and the `calcPos` function was implemented by you, right? I can see two possibilities here: 1 - the `calcPos` function (it might be a slow calculation) ... or 2 - the way you are calling `drawFront` (timeout, interval, animationFrame?). Plz post all you code is a fiddle or bin so I can take a closer look.

Comment: Performance wise, drawing and filling boxes.  SVG's are made for this.

Comment: svg will make things even slower since you will have all dom objects in memory ... don't do it. And you just need to declare a variable once. `var tempPosition` is declared several times in you code.

Comment: ok. Here is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/fswxtxyz/

Comment: You can also the the whole code on my github; https://github.com/Quoteme/Fluchtpunkt3D Maybe this will help you

Comment: Why do you draw even when nothing changed ? Why don't you create a variable instead of calling hundred times `path.to.your.utter.deep.method.that.your.browser.has.to.follow.each["call"]`? Do you realize your call to `calcPos` create a new object every time, I didn't count it exactly, but it seems like you call it 52 times per frame (@60fps => 3120 new objects marked for GC every seconds). GC is slow when it kicks in. Try to avoid it as much as possible. Actually, you should avoid creating any object during animation, and just update previously created ones.